# Strange behavior with gtools::mixedsort package in R

Tags: r, sorting, alphanumeric

I like to use the mixedsort/order function from gtools package to make alphanumeric sorting. However I faced a very weird behaviou in which in certain circustances it does not work well with the character E. See some examples. Can someone help me ? What is wrong?

Correct sorting:

```
> mixedsort(c("P0A1","P0B1","P0C1","P0D1","P0G1","P0F1"))
[1] "P0A1" "P0B1" "P0C1" "P0D1" "P0F1" "P0G1"
```

Incorrect sorting for character E:

```
> mixedsort(c("P0A1","P0E1","P0C1","P0D1","P0G1","P0F1"))
[1] "P0E1" "P0A1" "P0C1" "P0D1" "P0F1" "P0G1"
```

Correct sorting for character E:

```
> mixedsort(c("PA1","PE1","PC1","PD1","PG1","PF1"))
[1] "PA1" "PC1" "PD1" "PE1" "PF1" "PG1"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R `0E1` is floating point 0:

```
0E1
## [1] 0
```

It seems you will need to give it some help. Insert a space after the last non-digit, sort and then remove it.

```
sub(" ", "", mixedsort(sub("^(.*\\D)", "\\1 ", x)))
## [1] "P0A1" "P0C1" "P0D1" "P0E1" "P0F1" "P0G1"
```

Comment: If this is the cause, please report to the maintainer of [gtools](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gtools) - I'm sure they want to know and at a minimum document this "feature" or, better, provide a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. It can be fixed by adding a _ character in between like:  "P0_A1". Will communicate to the developer, Thanks.