# R: unexpected natural sorting by gtools mixedsort

Tags: r, sorting, vector, natural-sort

I am just finding some unexpected behavior in `gtools::mixedsort` looking at how my outputs are supposedly naturally sorted.

I have an example like this:

```
aa=c("CD57","CD58","CD158","CD158b","CD158e","CD158e1","CD319","CD335")
gtools::mixedsort(aa)
```

My expected result would be:

```
[1] "CD57"    "CD58"    "CD158"   "CD158b"  "CD158e"  "CD158e1" "CD319"
[8] "CD335"
```

However I obtain this:

```
[1] "CD57"    "CD58"    "CD158"   "CD158b"  "CD158e"  "CD319"   "CD335"
[8] "CD158e1"
```

Is this correct? What is the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CD158e1` is treated as as `1580` here, because:

```
>>> 158e1
1580.0
>>>
```

`158e1` is an Euler number with `e`, so it gives one extra `0`, `e2` would give 2 extra and so on...

So that's why it get's parsed as the last one in the list.

---

As mentioned in [the documentation of `mixedsort`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gtools/versions/3.9.2/topics/mixedsort):

> These functions sort or order character strings containing embedded
> numbers so that the numbers are numerically sorted rather than sorted
> by character value. I.e. "Aspirin 50mg" will come before "Aspirin
> 100mg". In addition, case of character strings is ignored so that "a",
> will come before "B" and "C".

Comment: @DaniCee Yeap! :)

Comment: @DaniCee Added more info now :)

Comment: And I guess there is no option to avoid this behavior right?

Comment: @DaniCee Check this out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60358347/strange-behavior-with-gtoolsmixedsort-package-in-r